# Как ставить метки в emacs

Tags: текст, emacs

Можно ли ставить метки в тексте, чтобы можно было быстро по ним перепрыгивать. Сейчас мне удобнее через поиск добираться к нужному выражению. А если мне надо вернуться обратно, то я использую `ctrl+x ctrl-x`, но это не совсем то что нужно, и возвращаться можно только к последнему прыжку. В принципе перебираться по тексту с помощью поиска вполне удобно, но если есть вариант по-удобнее, то не хотелось бы терять такую возможность.
P.s. желательно без установки сторонних пакетов

Comment: Тут про пометки написано http://alexott.net/ru/emacs/emacs-manual/emacs_13.html

Comment: Я использую `point-to-register` -- *`"It is bound to C-x r SPC, C-x r C-SPC, C-x r C-@."`*

Comment: @avp, отлично, то что надо! Оформите ответ и я его зачту. Я нашел, но для остальных кому интересно, допишите как добираться до сохраненных позиций(`C-x r j {регистр}`). И еще про закладки было бы неплохо дописать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Emacs есть так называемые *регистры* (registers) -- это именованные одним символом разделы, в которых можно сохранять текст, прямоугольные области текста, позиции в буфере (и другие штучки) для дальнейшего использования. В каждый момент регистр может хранить только одну из этих категорий.

Для сохранения текущей позиции (места где находится курсор) нужно вызвать команду
 `point-to-register`, которая по умолчанию привязана к  `C-x r SPC, C-x r C-SPC, C-x r C-@`.
Команда запросит имя регистра (один символ). В  качестве имени можно вводить любые символы.

Для перехода в содержащуюся в регистре позицию служит команда `jump-to-register`, привязанная к `C-x r j`, которая также спрашивает имя регистра.

Подробнее см. раздел [Registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Registers.html) в документации [The Emacs Editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html#Top)